# Swift Bridging Header - New Target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have an objective-c project with one class implemented in Swift. The project has with two targets: A and B. For both of them the Xcode created the bridging header files, `A-Swift.h` and `B-Swift.h`, and the app builds and runs both targets without any issue.

I've added two new targets, C and D (this time no bridging header files were created). If I build A and B there is no issue, but if I build C and D the build isn't completed because it can't find the `B-Swift.h`.

Target C is just a duplication of A, and D a duplication of B, with of course some properties updated in the plist file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the same generated header name for different targets. Otherwise you'd need to include all generated headers in each `.m` file or change the import based on target you run. 
You can go to `Build Settings` -> `Swift Compiler General` and change `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` to `A-Swift.h` for all your targets.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make all the targets use the same bridging header, you need to change the Objective-C Bridging Header value. I did NOT have to change the 
Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name

under your Build Settings > Search swift compiler> Under Swift Compiler-General> Change the value of Bridging header. 
Repeat the process for all the existing targets.

Comment: What if I need to ignore some libraries in one of the targets? Any idea on that?